# struts2-sjg:gridColumn-single quote disappear

Tags: struts2-jquery

so this is what I have in my jsp:

```
 <sjg:gridColumn name="abc"
                 title="abc #"
                 formatter="%{isAbc()
                      ? 'abc.id'
                      : 'abcd.id'}"
                 sortable="false" width="130"/>
```

I want to have `formatter="'abc.id'"`
but it is giving me  `formatter="abc.id"`  after show in html

Any way that I can get `formatter="'abc.id'"` instead of `formatter="abc.id"` ?

Comment: What this formatter is for? The ognl support full of escapes.

Comment: @RomanC  https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/FormatGrid

Comment: Put quotes inside the string value?

Comment: yes single quote in string value @DaveNewton

Comment: Yeah, I'm saying put them in the ognl string value.

Comment: @DaveNewton did not understand. can you provide a code example?

Comment: ... `? "’abc.id’"` etc. You know, like any other string.

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah, I tried that, it does not work

Comment: You can create a custom formatter @kklalala